# how to forward and broadcast UDP packet from one network to another?

Tags: router, udp, broadcast

I want to forward udp packets broadcasted in one network to another. how can i do this ? I know we can put router in between and router can forward, but router can only unicast not broadcast.

Comment: Any particular protocol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridging_(networking)) the networks and renumber one of them accordingly. Or
2. [Multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast) instead. Be sure to select a [multicast address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address) that is routable, not one that's limited to the local link.

Comment: One possible way to bridge the networks is through a layer 2 VPN such as OpenVPN in bridge mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the software on the router (by building a router out of a PC, or a home gateway box with aftermarket Linux firmware distro on it), you could write your own traffic handling rules, or put your own daemon on the router to look for and forward the broadcast packets you care about, even if those kinds of frames are not typically routed.

Comment: Problem is unless you control all routers between the networks then at least one of them is very likely going to see the broadcast and just drop it, i.e. your ISP is not going to forward broadcast UDP traffic.  Tunneling the traffic using a VPN or other method is the workaround.

Comment: @ultrasawblade When he says, "I know we can put a router in between", that suggests he's talking about two networks at the same site.